# how to match string literal type when concat string in typescript

Tags: string, typescript, literals

```js
type TA = 'App' | 'Area';
type TB = 'getAppDetail' | 'getAreaDetail';
const a: TA = 'App';
const b: TB = `get${a}Detail`;
```

But `get${a}Detail` returns a string type. And it doesn't match type TB.

Is there any solutions to solve the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with TypeScript 4.1 [Template Literal Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#template-literal-types) + [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) / `as const`:

```
// given
type TA = 'App' | 'Area';
type TB = 'getAppDetail' | 'getAreaDetail';
const a: TA = 'App';
const aError = 'Nap';

// tests
const bInferred = `get${a}Detail` as const; // "getAppDetail"
const bChecked: TB = `get${a}Detail` as const; // works
const bChecked_Error: TB = `getNapDetail`; // error
const bChecked_Error2: TB = `get${aError}Detail` as const; // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHMEsDcFMDsBQAXAngB1qAKgQVALygDku66xoAPibgE6wCGxA3ChltgEKEnizIy6ACIDGkADaUaxfoIaNRycVLYBjAPbwAzslCMAXDnxFS5Vok069jAKJ06Gur2IA5RhTaIQoZLF3allq6oABGAJLwAGawDrAAJrwABnIAJADejAC+SipJ+tqgVrosoD4ARHJCuZLlQdZhAMIAFrBqANYJRtzJaZk5YpL5jIXFyKU+AO5O7YFjTa0dCQD69o503TxEKQLuIoMSSRNgsev1IaEtbZ3xqw5OAEybvQIZdvd0A8pDBUXB42UTh8gA)

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript will not infer a concatenated string to a custom type automatically so you'll have to infer it to `TB` manually:

```
type TA = 'App' | 'Area';
type TB = 'getAppDetail' | 'getAreaDetail';
const a: TA = 'App';
const b = `get${a}Detail` as TB;
```

[See code snippet at CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-hypatia-cqo4n)